# Azure API Management with Service Fabric

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-service-fabric

**Problem:**

I want to setup a CI/CD where whenever I publish changes to my SF API, it automatically updates the endpoints of the API in the Azure API Management instance.

**How do I plan on doing that?**

I push changes to my GitHub repo, it is built, and it gets deployed. Second step in the release is a PowerShell script which updates an existing Azure APIM API with the Swagger doc of the newly deployed SF API.

**Whats the problem?**

Well, you can't pass through the gateway unless you have an endpoint defined in the Azure APIM API. I can define a Swagger endpoint there by default, but whenever the PowerShell update is run, it'll remove that endpoint because the Swagger generated does not have itself in it, which is totally logical.

If I expose the Swagger endpoint without the gateway somehow, that posses a security threat, and kind of kills the purpose of Azure APIM gateway.

**My Setup?**

Incoming Request -> Azure APIM -> Service Fabric App (Public/Internal)

- Internal SF Apps will ideally not be exposed through the gateway and are only used for inter app communication.

Any help in this regard is highly appreciated since I am kind of blocked on this :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate API in APIM just to access swagger AT SF side and don't update this API as a part of CI/CD. If may even be made to look from outside as a part of said API. For example if your main API has suffix of "/myApi", then you swagger API suffix may be defined as "/myApi/swagger.json" (operation inside it may have empty URL template).

Or you could as a part of you CI/CD recreate swagger access operation inside newly imported API. This endpoint will be used later to fetch swagger for next import.

Comment: These all seem like hacks, I want something that feels a bit more natural.
As for creating a seperate API, I thought about it before but can I even define multiple backend SF endpoints against a single APIM API?? I couldn't find anything on this.

Comment: Well, it is expected that during import you can provide either spec file or publicly accessible URL of one. If you rely on APIM service to provide publicly accessible URL for a spec that is part of API you're updating... It will seem like a hack.

Comment: Not sure why you need to have one API in APIM. You can create dedicated API that is used only to provide access to your spec and never touch this enpoint in future only using it for import. Make sure to secure it though, as APIM is publicly facing and you seem to want to avoid exposing your APIs.

Comment: So APIM automatically protects all the APIs within it with a key so swagger via APIM would be protected. As for having a separate API to provide just the specs, well, I don't like that idea. I'd rather go with your first approach than. I have a meeting scheduled with one of the Azure Architects, let me talk to them and share with you as well what they suggest.